# How can i select row in one datagrid when i click in another table using GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, datagrid

I have two tables, and i want to select appropriate row in first table when i select row in second table.  I've done this as following

```
for (DataRow<Cell> row : formDataTable.getVisibleItems()) {
            if (row.getIndex().equals(rowIndex.intValue())) {
                formDataTable.getSelectionModel().setSelected(row, true);
            }
}
```

But i don't see it as visual selected row. I see selected row from second table, but i should see it on first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It done through a setSelected.

1. Make sure that you use a right `selectionModel` for yours dataGrid.
2. Use `setSelected` method of `dataGrid`

If you want to have opportunity selecting row on other pages you should use `ProvidesKey` and manualy set necessary page

My code below

```
// variables 
@UiField
DataGrid<DataRow<Cell>> formDataTable;

public static final ProvidesKey<DataRow<Cell>> KEY_PROVIDER = new ProvidesKey<DataRow<Cell>>() {
    @Override
    public Object getKey(DataRow<Cell> item) {
        return item.getIndex();
    }
};

private SingleSelectionModel<DataRow<Cell>> selectionModel;


// this code must be within constructor
selectionModel = new SingleSelectionModel<DataRow<Cell>>(KEY_PROVIDER);
formDataTable.setSelectionModel(selectionModel);

// method to select should view as
@Override
public void setFocus(final Long rowIndex) {
    DataRow<Cell> row = new DataRow<Cell>();
    row.setIndex(rowIndex.intValue());
    selectionModel.setSelected(row, true);

    // go to essential page
    Long page = rowIndex / pager.getPageSize() + (rowIndex % pager.getPageSize() > 0 ? 1:0);
    pager.setPage(page.intValue() - 1);
}
```

Comment: Is this an answer? If not, please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22858014/edit) your question, add this there and then please delete this post.